# Asymptotic distribution for t-test with time series

Tags: regression, time-series, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I once read the following statement:

Given the following equation

$ Y_t= c + a Y_{t-1} + \theta_t$

1. If $c\neq 0$, then the t-ratio for testing $H_0 : a=1$ is asymptotically normal.
2. If $c=0$, then the t-ratio for testing will converge to another nonstandard asymptotic distribution.

But I do not know how to get the above two conclusions.

Comment: Is $a=1$ a requirement? Or does the same hold for some arbitrary constant $a=a_0$?

Comment: yes, a=1 is a requirement.